# Usage of noxious, nocuous and their opposites

Tags: differences, adjectives, word-usage

I came across the word *nocuous*. It seems that this word is rarely used (and even the spell-checking of my browser does mark it as a mistake). [*Noxious*, in comparison](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nocuous,noxious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), is used way more often.

[image: image description]

Interestingly, the opposite statement can be applied to their antonyms *innocuous* and *innoxious*. Now [the comparison between both](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=innocuous,innoxious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows a clear tendency to the use of *innocuous* (and my browser's spell-checking marks the latter).

[image: image description]

The question is, in which contexts should I have a preference to *nocuous/innocuous* and when should I go with *noxious/innoxious*? Or are possibly only *innocuous* and *noxious* in practical use, while the others are rather formal? Perhaps, *innocuous* is the well-established opposite to *noxious* in colloquial?

Comment: @BrianHooper Thanks for your edit. Is this really the correct placement, the comma preceding the bracket, although only the part in brackets makes the comma permitted.

Comment: @Em1, I'd think, to be honest, that no commas are really necessary in this context. Certainly a comma as the first letter in a bracket is very strange. Perhaps that is worth another question?

Comment: @BrianHooper In addition to the google books data, you can see in the COHA corpus that innoxious has fallen out of use by the 20th century: http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/x3.asp?xx=1&w11=innoxious&r=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Innoxious* is used in medical, chemical, and certain manufacturing fields to mean that a substance is not injurious, hurtful, or damaging, especially to tissues. Do a Google search for "innoxious medical" and you get [768,000 results.](http://www.google.com/#q=innoxious+medical&hl=en&prmd=imvns&ei=dkzAT6XpKcWT6gHg0IXRCg&start=0&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e114240fdc1e65f0&biw=1267&bih=629) Of course *innoxious* is the antonym of *noxious* and a synonym for *innocuous*. (Those three words appear in *Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary*, 30th Ed. *Nocuous*, however, did not merit an entry.) Both *Dorland's* and *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary* include in their definitions of *noxious* the word "pernicious," which in medical dictionaries is defined as "tending to a fatal tissue." That is, something that is *noxious* can be very damaging to tissues, irreparably so.

So to answer your question, the most commonly used words (as you suspected) are *innocuous* and *noxious*. *Innoxious* has use in certain fields. *Nocuous* is just not used.

Comment: Shouldn't *tissue* be *issue*? (I don't have medical dictionaries on hand.)

Comment: @TimLymington, No. Tissue is correct. It kills the tissue.

Comment: Interestingly, in some non-medical dictionaries, ‘innoxious’ is not found at all, while ‘nocuous’ is found, though marked as _literary_ or _formal_.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting question: I didn't know that there were such words as nocuous and innoxious. I'd suggest the answer would be that very few people have heard of these words, and therefore noxious and innocuous would be preferable.

Comment: I think using either, however in-nocently, would be ob-noxious.